# Javafx replacement for swing javax.swing.text.Document

Tags: swing, javafx

I have a swing app which overrides javax.swing.text.Document to limit the content of an underlying document to some characters and text length. I would like to port my appp to Javafx but I don't know if there is aJavafx equivalent for this class. Is there a way to replace it in Javafx?

What my class is doing is wrapping a Document to add new capabilities (in my case limitations). A lot of the methods only defer to the underlying Document I use, but some of them add my limitations, which are:

- line length limitations
- number of lines limitations
- upper case limitation
- characters limitations

  ```
  public class ConstrainedDocument implements Document {
   protected Document document = null;
   private boolean limitLength = false;
   private boolean limitLines = false;
   private int maxLength = -1;
   private int maxLines = -1;
   private boolean limitText = false;
   private String allowedText = null;
   private boolean uppercase = false;

   /**
    * Constructor.
    *
    * @param doc the document
    */
   public ConstrainedDocument(Document doc) {
      this.document = doc;
   }

   /**
    * Constructor.
    */
   public ConstrainedDocument() {
      this.document = new PlainDocument();
   }

   public Document getDocument() {
      return document;
   }

   /**
    * Limits the allowed length for each line of the document.
    * 
    * @param maxLength the maximum line length
    */
   public void setMaximumLength(int maxLength) {
      this.maxLength = maxLength;
      this.limitLength = true;
   }

   /**
    * Limits the allowed number of lines for the document.
    * 
    * @param maxLines the maximum number of lines
    */
   public void setMaximumLines(int maxLines) {
      this.maxLines = maxLines;
      this.limitLines = true;
   }

   /**
    * Limits the characters allowed to compose the document.
    *
    * @param allowedText the String defining the allowed characters
    */
   public void setAllowedText(String allowedText) {
      this.allowedText = allowedText;
      this.limitText = true;
   }

   /**
    * Forces only upper case.
    * 
    * @param uppercase true if only upper case are forced
    */
   public void setUpperCase(boolean uppercase) {
      this.uppercase = uppercase;
   }

   /**
    * Resets all the limitations and settings for this document.
    */
   public void resetLimitations() {
      this.limitText = false;
      this.limitLength = false;
      this.limitLines = false;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the allowed length for each line of the document.
    * 
    * @return the maximum line length
    */
   public int getMaximumLineLength() {
      return maxLength;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the allowed number of lines for the document.
    * 
    * @return the maximum number of lines
    */
   public int getMaximumLines() {
      return maxLines;
   }

   /**
    * Returns true if the maximum length of the text is set.
    * 
    * @return true if the maximum length of the text is set
    *
    * @see #getMaximumLineLength()
    */
   public boolean isLineLengthLimited() {
      return limitLength;
   }

   /**
    * Returns true if the number of allowed lines is limited.
    * 
    * @return true if the maximum number of lines is set
    *
    * @see #getMaximumLines()
    */
   public boolean isLinesLimited() {
      return limitLines;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the characters allowed to compose the document.
    * 
    * @return the allowed characters as a string
    */
   public String getAllowedText() {
      return allowedText;
   }

   /**
    * Returns true if the allowed characters are limited.
    * 
    * @return true if the allowed characters are limited
    *
    * @see #getAllowedText()
    */
   public boolean isTextLimited() {
      return limitText;
   }

   /**
    * Returns true if the insertion is forced to upper case characters.
    * 
    * @return true if the insertion is forced to upper case characters
    */
   public boolean isUpperCase() {
      return uppercase;
   }

   /**
    * Extends the remove method from the parent Document class to fire remove events
    * when lines are removed.
    */
   @Override
   public void remove(int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
      document.remove(offset, length);
   }

   /**
    * Extends the insertString method from the parent Document class. This adds :
    * <ul>
    * <li>the ability to force upper case characters insertion if the {@link #isUpperCase()}
    * property is set</li>
    * <li>the ability to block insertion of unauthorized characters if the {@link #isTextLimited()}
    * property is set. In that case, the text is limited to the {@link #getAllowedText()} characters</li>
    * <li>the ability to limit the number of lines if the {@link #isLinesLimited()} property is set. In
    * that case, the number of allowed lines is limited to {@link #getMaximumLines()}</li>
    * <li>the ability to limit the length of each line if the {@link #isLineLengthLimited()} property
    * is set. In that case, the length for each line is limited to {@link #getMaximumLineLength()}</li>
    * </ul>
    * <p>
    * It also fire insertion events when lines are inserted.</p>
    */
   @Override
   public void insertString(int offset, String inputStr, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
      String str = inputStr;
      // handle showSpaces, upper case and characters limitation
      if (uppercase || limitText) {
         StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (uppercase) {
               c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            }
            if (limitText) {
               if (allowedText.indexOf(c) != -1) {
                  buf.append(c);
               }
            } else {
               buf.append(c);
            }
         }
         str = buf.toString();
      }
      Element root = document.getDefaultRootElement();
      AbstractDocument.LeafElement elt = (AbstractDocument.LeafElement) root.getElement(root.getElementIndex(offset));
      // Gets the text to insert, taking care of adding new lines in the process
      str = getTextToInsert(root, elt, str);
      if (str.length() > 0) {
         document.insertString(offset, str, a);
      }
      // if only the length of the text is limited
   }

   /**
    * Returns the text to insert on the current line.
    *
    * @param root the root element of the Document
    * @param elt the leaf element, interface the line of text where to insert the text
    * @param t the String to insert
    */
   protected String getTextToInsert(Element root, AbstractDocument.LeafElement elt, String t) {
      // Gets the length of the line where to insert the text
      int begin = elt.getStartOffset();
      int end = elt.getEndOffset();
      int length = end - begin - 1;
      // Gets the number of lines
      int lineCount = root.getElementCount();

      // iterate through the text to insert, taking care of the line length
      // and number of lines limitation
      StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

      for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
         char c = t.charAt(i);

         // if this is a new line, we must check if we are allowed to add a new line
         if (c == '\n') {
            // we are not allowed to add a new line
            if (limitLines && lineCount >= maxLines) {
               break;
            } else {
               // ok, we can add a new line
               buf.append(c);
               lineCount++;
               length = 0;
            }
            // this is not a new line character, we add the character if we can
         } else {
            // if no line length limitation, we just add the character
            if (!limitLength) {
               buf.append(c);
            } else if (length >= maxLength) {
               // else current length >= maximum line length, we try to add a new line
               // not allowed, finish to add
               if (limitLines && lineCount >= maxLines) {
                  break;
               } else {
                  // adding a new line is allowed, there is remaining available lines
                  buf.append('\n').append(c);
                  lineCount++;
                  length = 1;
               }
               // current length < maximum line length, we just add the character
            } else {
               buf.append(c);
               length++;
            }
         }
      }
      return buf.toString();
   }

   /**
    * Return the text of this Document. Special spaces characters will be trasnformed to "real" spaces.
    */
   @Override
   public String getText(int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
      String text = document.getText(offset, length);

      return text;
   }

   /**
    * get the offset position in the Document for the selected line.
    *
    * @param line the selected line
    * @return the offset position.
    */
   public int getOffsetPosition(int line) {
      int offset = 0;
      int count = 0;

      if (line == 0) {
         return offset;
      }

      Element root = document.getDefaultRootElement();

      try {
         for (int i = 0; i < root.getElementCount(); i++) {
            AbstractDocument.LeafElement elt = (AbstractDocument.LeafElement) root.getElement(i);

            offset = elt.getStartOffset();
            String text = getText(elt.getStartOffset(), elt.getEndOffset() - elt.getStartOffset());

            if (count == line) {
               break;
            }
            if (text.charAt(text.length() - 1) == '\n') {
               count++;
            }
         }
      } catch (BadLocationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return offset;
   }

   @Override
   public int getLength() {
      return document.getLength();
   }

   @Override
   public void render(Runnable runnable) {
      document.render(runnable);
   }

   @Override
   public void addDocumentListener(DocumentListener listener) {
      document.addDocumentListener(listener);
   }

   @Override
   public void removeDocumentListener(DocumentListener listener) {
      document.removeDocumentListener(listener);
   }

   @Override
   public void addUndoableEditListener(UndoableEditListener listener) {
      document.addUndoableEditListener(listener);
   }

   @Override
   public void removeUndoableEditListener(UndoableEditListener listener) {
      document.removeUndoableEditListener(listener);
   }

   @Override
   public Element getDefaultRootElement() {
      return document.getDefaultRootElement();
   }

   @Override
   public Element[] getRootElements() {
      return document.getRootElements();
   }

   @Override
   public Position getEndPosition() {
      return document.getEndPosition();
   }

   @Override
   public Position getStartPosition() {
      return document.getStartPosition();
   }

   @Override
   public Position createPosition(int i) throws BadLocationException {
      return document.createPosition(i);
   }

   @Override
   public void getText(int i, int i0, Segment segment) throws BadLocationException {
      document.getText(i, i0, segment);
   }

   @Override
   public Object getProperty(Object key) {
      return document.getProperty(key);
   }

   @Override
   public void putProperty(Object key, Object value) {
      document.putProperty(key, value);
   }
  }
  ```

Comment: You can provide this functionality with a `TextFormatter`

Comment: See the [Javadocs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) and this good [tutorial](https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/textformatter1)

Comment: Thank you!! I will look at the documentation of this class. It seems to answer my needs!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality can be implemented in JavaFX using a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html).

This quick example implements a maximum text length, for example. The other functionality in your Swing example can be implemented similarly:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.maxtextlength;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        Spinner<Integer> maxLengthSpinner = new Spinner<>(10, 200, 100);
        maxLengthSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldLength, newLength) ->
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText().substring(0, Math.min(newLength, textArea.getLength())))
        );
        textArea.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
            int proposedTextLength = change.getControlNewText().length();
            if (proposedTextLength > maxLengthSpinner.getValue()) {
                // truncate text to maximum allowed length:
                int newTextLength = change.getText().length();
                int delta = proposedTextLength - maxLengthSpinner.getValue();
                change.setText(change.getText().substring(0, newTextLength - delta));
                // adjust caret:
                change.setCaretPosition(change.getCaretPosition() - delta);
                change.setAnchor(change.getAnchor() - delta);
            } 
            return change;
        }));
        Label length = new Label();
        length.textProperty().bind(textArea.textProperty().map(String::length).map(len -> "Length: "+len));
        length.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        HBox controls = new HBox(5, new Label("Max text length:"), maxLengthSpinner);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(textArea);
        root.setBottom(length);
        root.setTop(controls);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

I sometimes find the use of `TextFormatter` a little non-intuitive (though it is very powerful). You might want to refer to this [excellent tutorial](https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/textformatter1).